# shell script * operation gives too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I m doing a simple calculator with option of choosing to continue or not . But when I try multiplying operation I get error in the console :

```
calculator.sh: line 17: [: too many arguments
calculator.sh: line 22: [: too many arguments
calculator.sh: line 27: [: too many arguments
calculator.sh: line 32: [: too many arguments
```

Which basically means all my operations has this error , but that is not true when I use them , they act normally .
I searched in stack overflow for similarities , but the examples are different . I escaped the * with slash , but I think it shouts the error in the comparing with the character "*" in order getting to the body of the if statement. 
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
choice="Y"
while [ $choice == "Y" ]
do
echo -n "Enter first value:"
read firstvar
echo -n "Enter second value:"
read secondvar
echo -n "Enter last value:"
read compvar
echo -n "Enter operation:"
read ops
counter=0
result=0
while [ $result != $compvar ]
do
if [ $ops == "+" ]
then result=$((firstvar+secondvar))
echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
read choice
break
elif [ $ops == "-" ]
then result=$((firstvar-secondvar))
echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
read choice
break
elif [ $ops == "*" ]
then result=$((firstvar\*secondvar))
echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
read choice
break
elif [ $ops == "/" ]
then result=$((firstvar/secondvar))
echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
read choice
break
else
echo "Input valid operation !!!"
echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
read choice
break
fi
counter=$((counter+1))
done
done
```

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net.

Comment: BTW, a proper [mcve] for this can be a little as one line of code. `ops='*'; if [ $ops == "*" ]; then echo "Understood this as a multiplication"; fi` is all it takes to let someone else reproduce your problem, and *more reliably* than when the code is trying to read from a terminal and thus depends on user behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely not because the `"*"` in script, but because of an asterisk in your `$ops` variable.

You should double-quote the variables to avoid globbing being applied to them; rewrite your tests like this:

```
elif [ "$ops" = "*" ]
```

Here's a very helpful [resource for checking your shell scripts](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: You don't need to escape `*` inside quotes.

Comment: Right. Copied that over from the original question code.

Comment: `==` isn't guaranteed to be supported inside `[ ]`. Use `=` instead, per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Better yet, skip the `[ $ops = ...` tests and do `case $ops in  ...`

Answer (score 0):

> First, see the comment by Charles Duffy WRT "==" vs "=" for string tests.
>   Change occurrences of $ops to "${ops}".
>   Remove the escape in result=$((firstvar*secondvar)).
>   I took the liberty to reformat the script just a bit.
>   Hope this helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
choice="Y"
while [ $choice = "Y" ]
do
  echo -n "Enter first value:"
  read firstvar
  echo -n "Enter second value:"
  read secondvar
  echo -n "Enter last value:"
  read compvar
  echo -n "Enter operation:"
  read ops
  counter=0
  result=0
  while [ $result != $compvar ]
  do
    if [ "${ops}" = "+" ]; then
      result=$((firstvar+secondvar))
      echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
      read choice
      break
    elif [ "${ops}" = "-" ]; then
      result=$((firstvar-secondvar))
      echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
      read choice
      break
    elif [ "${ops}" = "*" ]; then
      result=$((firstvar*secondvar))
      echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
      read choice
      break
    elif [ "${ops}" = "/" ]; then
      result=$((firstvar/secondvar))
      echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
      read choice
      break
    else
      echo "Input valid operation !!!"
      echo "Do you want to continue ? Y/N"
      read choice
      break
    fi
    counter=$((counter+1))
  done
done
```

Comment: `"${ops}"` doesn't have any reliability/robustness benefit over `"$ops"` -- and if you're aiming for a refactor, I'd consider switching to a `case` statement. Should also add extra quotes where they're warranted (see http://shellcheck.net/ results -- that'll point out `"$compvar"`, for instance).

Comment: (...and actually, shellcheck suggests less quoting than is actually a good idea in the Real World, because presumably the whole point of `choice=Y` is to be a standin for `read choice` -- but as soon as you do that, `"$choice"` needs to be quoted too).